# Error Timeout ASP.NET SP

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo un detalle al momento de cargar el `StoredProcedure` y llenarlo en un `datatable`, me marca el error:

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated"

ya probé con ...

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(@"SERVER=server;DataBase=db; user=us;password=pass;Connect Timeout=120;");
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("stored_procedure", conn);
```

y cuando ejecuto el `SP`en `SQL Server` a lo mucho tarda 1min en cargar la info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta subir el timeout del comando, es diferente que el de la cadena de conexión.

Prueba con esto

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
comando.CommandTimeout = 120;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cómo te ha indicado AldoRomo88 debes definir el TimeOut del `SQLCommand` para que este funcione cómo quieres (en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25992217/1468942) lo cuentan con más detalle):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
  cmd.Connection = conn ;
  cmd.CommandTimeout = 240; //en segundos
  //etc...
}
```

Pero me gustaría añadir que a veces hay inconsistencias entre ejecutar una SP des del propio SQL Server comparado con ejecutarlo des de C#. Si quieres aprender más de ello este [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) lo cuenta todo al respecto.

A modo resumen, muchas veces esto va lento debido a procesos internos del SQL que sólo se ejecutan si se llama a la SP des de C#, para solucionarlo lanza este comando:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [TABLE NAME]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_recompile @objname = N''
GO
```